# link, script tags between </body> and </html>

Tags: html, syntaxhighlighter

I've just started using [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/whatsnew.html).
I looked at their HTML source code for [this page](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/manual/api/autoloader.html) and noticed that they put some link and script tags between `</body>` and `</html>`. I guess it helps the page turns up faster plus with their new `autoload` function. But is that valid/okay (according to the HTML validator, it is not)? will it cause any weird stuff in some browsers?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But is that valid

No

> /okay?

Subjective

> will it cause any weird stuff in some browsers?

Doubtful, but you might as well move the script to just before `</body>` as is traditional for end-of-document script loading.

Comment: will it slow down the site though?

Comment: By starting the script loading 9 bytes earlier? No.

Comment: if you look at the very last script tag `/SyntaxHighlighter/scripts/main.js`. It looks like it has to be called at the end of the page anyway. If I put it on top it won't work

Comment: Nobody said anything about putting it at the top.