# Bootstrap Carousel-inner "autoplay"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

Can some one help me out? There are a few things wrong here I know. Why do i have to link bootstrap.min.js at the end of the header and at the bottom of the page. Ive tried using one at a time but it doesnt work. The next thing is that I want carousel to start when I load the page and when I click the controllers; not just when i click the controllers.

```
    <head>
        <title>The James Baldwin School</title>
        <link href="Framework/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="Main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <header>
        <div class="navbar-wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div id="navtop" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">

        <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">The James Baldwin School</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Parents <b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>

            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Students <b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>

            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Teachers <b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>



    </div>
  </div><!-- /container -->
</div><!-- /navbar wrapper -->

        <!--- Javascript Bootstrap --->
        <script src="Framework/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</header>


<!-- Carousel
================================================== -->
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
  <div class="item active">
      <img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-BUrT0CP-6nQ/U1prUuv6VjI/AAAAAAAAFbY/a6PUNgNhSWM/s1600/1500x500-New-York-Skyline-Twitter-Header0017.jpg" style="width:100%" class="img-responsive">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Bootstrap 3 Carousel</h1>
          <p>Pictures slide with overlapping words</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="http://getbootstrap.com">Learn More</a>
        </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-jBZKbiHI_2U/U1pszgzFAbI/AAAAAAAAFcI/8xrxWuBse9o/s1600/1500x500-New-York-Skyline-Twitter-Header0024.jpg" class="img-responsive">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Each Slide can be different</h1>
          <p>I just need some one to pick the pictures and words</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="#">Learn more</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://mooxidesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/New-york-1500x500.jpg" class="img-responsive">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Percentage-based sizing</h1>
          <p>This Site is fully responsive and adjusts to the size of the browser your using. Meaning that it looks great on smart-phones</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="#">Browse gallery</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="icon-prev"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
    <span class="icon-next"></span>
  </a>  
</div>       
<!-- /.carousel -->


<!-- Marketing messaging and featurettes
================================================== -->
<!-- Wrap the rest of the page in another container to center all the content. -->

<div class="container marketing">

  <!-- Three columns of text below the carousel -->
<div id="about">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
      <img class="img-circle" src="http://placehold.it/140x140">
      <h2>Brady Smith</h2>
      <p>Principal Co-Director</p>
      <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#">View details »</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
      <img class="img-circle" src="http://placehold.it/140x140">
      <h2>Josh Heisler</h2>
      <p>Teacher Co-Director</p>
      <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#">View details »</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
      <img class="img-circle" src="http://placehold.it/140x140">
      <h2>Christine Olsen</h2>
      <p>Admissions</p>
      <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#">View details »</a></p>
    </div>
  </div><!-- /.row -->
</div>

  <!-- START THE FEATURETTES -->



  <!-- /END THE FEATURETTES -->


  <!-- FOOTER -->
  <footer>
    <p class="pull-right"><a href="#">Back to top</a></p>
    <p>This site was created by Isaac Perez. · <a href="http://www.google.com">Check it out</a></p>
  </footer>

  </div><!-- /.container -->

</body>
        <script src="Framework/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="Framework/js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
        var $ = jQuery.noConflict(); $(document).ready(function()  { $('#myCarousel').carousel({ interval: 3000, cycle: true }); });
        // ]]></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've just set up a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w2am9sgt/) containing the carousel of your example, jQuery version 2.1.3, bootstrap.js and bootstrap.css as external resources and your script to initalize the carousel

```
$('#myCarousel').carousel({
  interval: 3000,
  cycle: true
});
```

and it's working - it starts when the page loads and the controllers are working, too.
That it's not working for you can be an issue of loading bootstrap before jQuery - jQuery has to be included before bootstrap. To check if this is the case, see if there are any error / console message like "Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery". Also you're including 2 different jQuery versions  - 1.11.1 and 2.1.3. If not necessary, e.g. for some plugins relying on an older jQuery version, try just to load the latest one.
In addition, you're placing script tags between the closing body and html tags which can work, but isn't valid - see [link, script tags between </body> and </html>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9401157/link-script-tags-between-body-and-html) for details.
As reference for using different jQuery versions in case this would really be necessary, you can check http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Answer (score 11):

You could do it through the HTML with the `data-interval` tag.
Insert it into `<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">` so it looks like this:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="3000">
```

The value of `3000` can be adjusted to a higher number to decrease speed and a lower number to increase speed.

Comment: This does not autostart the carousel.  It just sets the `interval` between each slide.  Seems like there is no way to do this without `javascript`.

Comment: Though this does not answer the question - thanks for your answer as I didn't knew that. Nice to learn new things everyday.

Answer (score 0):

Add custom attribute `data-ride="carousel"` in the containing carousel div.
You can optionally add `data-interval="5000"` to change the slider change duration in milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

This is for Bootstrap v5.3 . Please read https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/carousel/#methods

In the carousel div set the data-bs-ride to 'carousel'.

```
    <div id="carouselExample" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel"> </id>
```

then, al last of the body tag write the follow code:

```
      <body>
      ...
        <script>
        const myCarouselElement = document.querySelector('#carouselExample')

        const carousel = new bootstrap.Carousel(myCarouselElement, {
           interval: 2000,
           touch: false
          })
        </script> 
    </body>
```